# Node.js event loop understanding (with a diagram)

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-loop

I've read [this](http://voidcanvas.com/setimmediate-vs-nexttick-vs-settimeout/) and [this](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#poll), watched [this](https://www.google.by/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjItu_ftcfVAhXsHpoKHdaeAhgQtwIIJDAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D8aGhZQkoFbQ&usg=AFQjCNHH9E_FFETO0UU8a5VSvAHYpYD-XA)...

I've made a diagram of how I understand it:

[image]

- Javascript callbacks (functions) can be present in the `current queue`, `check queue`, `close callbacks queue`, `timers queue` and `I/O callbacks queue`.
- Js code gets executed only from the `current queue` one function (task/job) at a time.
- Js code executed at the moment can add microtasks (jobs) to the `current queue` to be executed after itself and macrotasks (tasks) to the `check queue`. It can add tasks to other queues only inderectly by asking the API to do it.
- `Idle, prepare` phase is used for some internal node js business (maybe like garbage collection).
- `Poll` phase polls threads from the thread pool and fills the queues with appropriate callbacks.
- `Idle, prepare` and `poll` phases don't have queues for js callbacks associated with them.
- (four) Threads in the `thread pool` are all identical and have no specialization.
- Event loop takes and executes tasks one by one from each queue until it's empty then moves on to the next queue.
- Tasks in the queues don't have any jobs (microservices) associated with them. Jobs are created only during execution of a task or another job and are present only in the `current task queue`.

Is that understanding right or am I missing something?

MS Power Point .pptx file with the diagram can be found [here](http://graban-tota.rhcloud.com/fileserver/file?path=/downloads/event-loop.pptx).

Comment: This looks overly complicated to me. Maybe it is, but isn't a simpler model sufficient when you write code? I think it is not necessary to know all the details going on under the hood. Isn't it sufficient to know that there is a queue for the current tick, a queue for the next tick and the callbacks awaiting the timer or I/O.

Comment: I can't answer this, but I really appreciate the effort you put into your question.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer A simpler model is sufficient to write code, but still I'd like to know what's under the hood. georg, thanks :)

Comment: I think the documentation part is the right place where you can post this. Actually you don't have a precise question anybody  could answer, you just look for a peer review of your model.

Comment: @MarioSantini Do you mean there https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/node.js/topics? Maybe I'll take a closer look at how it works tomorrow. Should I edit the existing Eventloop topic or create a new one?

Comment: @grabantot yes. Not sure how to move your post, never did. You could just try, or ask on Meta or chat for help.

Comment: Stackoverflow.com documentation is dying. They decided to discontinue it.

Answer (score 2):

The diagram does seem quite complicated. I find a king analogy quite perfect in this context to have a grey level understanding about how event-loop works.

> Imagine the code you want to run is a king and node is the army of
>   servants.
>
> The day starts by one servant waking up the king and asking him if he
>   needs anything. The king gives the servant a list of tasks and goes
>   back to sleep a little longer. The servant now distributes those tasks
>   among his colleagues and they get to work.
>
> Once a servant finishes a task, he lines up outside the kings quarter
>   to report. The king lets one servant in at a time, and listens to
>   things he reports. Sometimes the king will give the servant more tasks
>   on the way out.
>
> Life is good, for the king's servants carry out all of his tasks in
>   parallel, but only report with one result at a time, so the king can
>   focus.

The king here is the main node process. This is how the nodejs is said to be single-threaded yet asynchronous.